# If Cell in Range Contains Value Then Insert Comment in Adjacent Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I hope the title clarifies the objective. All of my attempts fail miserably, for example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Range("A1:A10") = "blah"
        Range("A1:A10").Offset(0, 1).AddComment "fee"
        Range("A1:A10").Offset(0, 2).AddComment "fi"
        Range("A1:A10").Offset(0, 3).AddComment "fo"
    End With

End Sub
```

I have also tried this approach:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    For Each cell In Range("A1:A10")
        If cell.Value = "blah" Then
            cell.Value.Offset(0, 1).AddComment "fee"
            cell.Value.Offset(0, 2).AddComment "fi"
            cell.Value.Offset(0, 3).AddComment "fo"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

And this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Range(Target.Offset(0, 1).Address).AddComment
        Range(Target).Offset(0, 1).Comment.Visible = False
        Range(Target).Offset(0, 1).Comment.Text Text:="fee"            
    End With

End Sub
```

Note that the code is intended to be an event handler inserted in a particular worksheet. I clearly misunderstand VBA syntax with respect to ranges. Any assistance in making any of these subs work would be most appreciated.

Follow up: Tim's suggestion to use Worksheet_Calculate worked like a charm. I was able to accomplish my objective with this final variation on Tim's code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    'see if any changes are in the monitored range...
    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then

        For Each cell In rng.Cells
            If cell.Value = "blah" Then
                cell.Offset(0, 1).AddComment "fee"
                cell.Offset(0, 2).AddComment "fi"
                cell.Offset(0, 3).AddComment "fo"
            End If
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range, cell as Range

    On Error Goto haveError

    'see if any changes are in the monitored range...
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:A10"))

    If Not rng is Nothing Then
    'Next line prevents code updates from re-triggering this...
    '  (Not really needed if you're only adding comments)
    Application.EnableEvents=False
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.Value = "blah" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).AddComment "fee"
            cell.Offset(0, 2).AddComment "fi"
            cell.Offset(0, 3).AddComment "fo"
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents=True

    End If

    Exit Sub

haveError:
    msgbox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents=True



End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, thanks for this code. It runs as intended and you deserve the credit. There is, however, a complication that I did not anticipate in my initial request. In the above, the conditional trigger string "blah" is not a simple user-typed entry, but is generated by an application worksheet function. This causes your event handler code not to run. When the function is replaced with a user-typed string, your code works. Would you know how to modify your code to work if "blah" is generated by a worksheet function? Regards

Comment: You can use the worksheet_calculate event and check the values in the range of interest.  Since there's no Target parameter, you can just loop through the cells in A1:A10

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Still learning what this all means, but appreciate the pointers.